# Livestream 16 hour bike race

Tags: racing, camera, iphone

So next week a friend and I are going to be a support vehicle for a 500 km bike race. We wanted to setup something so we could live stream the whole event and wanted to ask if anyone has any experience with the best way of doing this. We will have around 4 or 5 stops evenly spread out on the track. One of our biggest challenges will probably be the battery.

The gear we have or is planning on getting

- 2 x GoPro 3 with extra battery
- iPhone 5 with a 50 GB data card. (Is that enough?)
- 3 x 6000 mAH [power packs](http://www.biltema.no/no/Kontor---Teknikk/Mobilt/Kabler-og-ladere/Powerpack-6000-mAh-2000036445/) to charge phone and GoPro

Our plan is to attach the phone and GoPro to one of the bikes and swap the power backs on each stop. Will this work? What other things should we consider?

We are planning on using https://livestream.com/
We will have a laptop in the car as well.

Will update this post with what we find out.

Comment: I wonder, can the iPhone 5 record for 16 hours without having an issues? At normal 1080p resolutions it may be OK but I do know some cameras and phones have a limit to how long they can record before they need a 'rest'.

Comment: This question may be better served in the http://video.stackexchange.com  stack. The only thing cycling related will be the video content.

Comment: Belongs on video.SE but that's not an option on the "relocate" section

Comment: The lack of a *belongs on another site* choice has long been an issue.

Comment: @Anders Our moderators may move your question to [video.se], where you'll get better answers. Just wait for that to happen, rather than cross-posting. BTW I don't think a 50 gb card will be *quite* enough.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid changing batteries, you could opt to get an external USB battery pack and power it off of that.  That way you could get a continuous stream. If you got a big enough battery pack, you would most likely be able to power the iPhone and GoPro off of a single battery pack provided you found one that was big enough.

Comment: They are using power banks (power packs). They'll just be swapping those out once they run out of juice, so the devices should remain powered the entire time.

Comment: Why not use the car's power, save swapping stuff out the whole time?

Comment: Yeah, don't know how I missed that part about the battery pack. It sounds like they still plan to have the camera off for a short amount of time at rest stops hence the "GoPro with extra battery". If you had a [sufficiently sized](http://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=14200) battery pack you could just power both devices continuously off the battery pack directly and there should be no need to switch anything.

Comment: The cameras will be attached to the bikes, so they can't use car power.

Comment: Most gopros only last 2 hours at best.   I run mine on a 9Ah USB battery and it would fill the 64 GB card in 20 hours,  before running out of battery.